# Install npgsql for PowerBI

Tags: powerpivot, npgsql, powerbi, powerquery

I'm not a programmer and I haven´t Visual Studio installed in my PC but I need npgsql to connect Microsoft PowerBI (Power Query) to a Postgres instance.

Is there a way to install it without having to compile it?
Is it necessary to do special configurations in my PC to make it work?

Thank you very much.
Javier

Comment: I have no idea about PowerBI, but as a general rule Npgsql can be installed as a simple nuget from https://www.nuget.org/packages/Npgsql/. There's a Visual Studio add-in for some Entity Framework operations as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To expand on @Shay's comment, you can use nuget if you want the latest version of Npgsql.

You don't need to install nuget.exe; you can down download the latest nuget package from http://packages.nuget.org/api/v1/package/Npgsql/

Rename the .NUPKG file as .ZIP and unzip it, and you'll find Npgsql.dll in /lib/net45.

[Office.com instructions](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Connect-to-a-PostgreSQL-database-Power-Query-bf941e52-066f-4911-a41f-2493c39e69e4?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) indicate you'll also need Mono.Security.dll, whcih you can download at http://packages.nuget.org/api/v1/package/Mono.Security/

Comment: Thank you very much Carl. I did as you said and Excel stopped asking for Npgsql but now I'm getting another error:

Comment: DataSource.Error: TlsClientStream.ClientAlertException: CertificateExpired
   en TlsClientStream.TlsClientStream.ParseCertificateMessage(Byte[] buf, Int32& pos)
   en TlsClientStream.TlsClientStream.TraverseHandshakeMessages()
   en TlsClientStream.TlsClientStream.GetInitialHandshakeMessages(Boolean allowApplicationData)
   en TlsClientStream.TlsClientStream.PerformInitialHandshake(String hostName, X509CertificateCollection clientCertificates, RemoteCertificateValidationCallback remoteCertificateValidationCallback, Boolean checkCertificateRevocation)

Comment: Which is wierd because I get the same error eather I have Mono.Security installed in the GAC or not.

Comment: It looks the install worked, but there was a problem with the secure connection to the database. You can try manually disabling encryption from Data Source Settings.

Comment: I don't find the option in Excel to disable encryption. Do you know where to configure it?

Comment: The problem was solved replacing our cerficates for the Certificate Authority signed certficates.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the [Office.com instructions](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Connect-to-a-PostgreSQL-database-Power-Query-bf941e52-066f-4911-a41f-2493c39e69e4?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) are slightly out of date, because the latest Npgsql [GitHub releases](https://github.com/npgsql/Npgsql/releases) aren't including compiled binary downloads. You can follow the Office.com instructions after downloading [an older GitHub release.](https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/releases/tag/v2.2.5)

(It may also work to just run the setup EXE instead of continuing with the Office.com instructions.)